# Null Pointer Exception setting MapType with Android Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception when trying to set the map type after committing the `MapFragment` and getting a reference to its map with `getMap()`.

I think the cause of the error is that the fragment hasn't been initialized yet and therefore I can't set the map type.

How can I know when this fragment has been initialized and I am allowed to call its public methods?  Is there an interface that I can implement in my `MainActivity` to know when the fragment has loaded?

Furthermore, why am I allowed to call `getMap()` on `mMapFragment` if it is not yet initialized?  Is it actually just the `GoogleMap` object that's not properly initialized?

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_container);

        fm = getFragmentManager();
        mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mMapFragment).commit();
        mGoogleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    }
}
```

And the XML for `main_container`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</FrameLayout>
```

And here's the LogCat output:

```
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matthewlogan.loopfinder/com.matthewlogan.loopfinder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:974)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at com.matthewlogan.loopfinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1098)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
10-09 11:17:16.457: E/AndroidRuntime(31679):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MapFragment`'s `GoogleMap` created via code is ready when:

1. its `onCreateView` has returned
2. Google Play Services app is installed and has correct version

If you want to get non-null `GoogleMap` in your `Activity`, do it in `onResume`:

```
if (mGoogleMap == null) {
    mGoogleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    if (mGoogleMap != null) {
        initMap();
    }
}
```

Double ifs ensure `initMap` is called only once per `Activity` instance and called only when `GoogleMap` is ready. It is a correct way of handling as the `GoogleMap` can be ready after user installs Google Play Services and returns to your app (`onResume` called for the second time).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know when this fragment has been initialized and I am allowed to call its public methods?

Configure the map fragment in one of its lifecycle methods, like `onActivityCreated()`.

Or, instead of using a `FragmentTransaction`, use a `<fragment>` tag in a layout.